How to compare each element of tensor and record result
I'm trying to check each element of a tensor to determine if it is closer to one of points I specify and then associate this element to this point somehow.
The data is like a table, axes X and Y are image pixel coordinates and values are depth values in millimeters (the depth_data variable).
My implementation currently is like this:
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import torch

def depth_clustering(num_points, depth_data):
    max = torch.max(depth_data)
    min = torch.min(depth_data)

    cluster_centers = create_cluster_centers(num_points, min, max)

    for y, line in enumerate(depth_data):
        for x, depth_val in enumerate(line):
            closest_cluster_center = None

            for cluster_center in cluster_centers:
                if closest_cluster_center is None:
                    closest_cluster_center = cluster_center
                    continue
                diff = torch.abs(torch.sub(depth_val, cluster_center.value))
                if torch.lt(diff, torch.abs(depth_val - closest_cluster_center.value)):
                    closest_cluster_center = cluster_center

            closest_cluster_center.add_and_adjust(torch.tensor([x, y, depth_val]))

    return cluster_centers

class DepthValueCluster:
    def __init__(self, value, init_capacity=100):
        self.value = value
        self.values = torch.zeros(init_capacity, 3)
        self.count = 0
        self.init_capacity = init_capacity
    def add(self, value):
        if self.values.size(0) < self.count + 1:
            new_array = torch.zeros((self.init_capacity, 3))
            self.values = torch.cat((self.values, new_array), 0)

        self.values[self.count] = value
        self.count += 1

    def add_and_adjust(self, value):
        self.add(value)
        self.move_cluster()

    def move_cluster(self):
        new = torch.mean(self.values, -2)
        self.value = new[2]

def create_cluster_centers(num_points, min, max):
    diff = max - min
    cluster_range = diff / num_points
    clusters = list()
    count = cluster_range / 2

    for i in range(num_points):
        clusters.append(DepthValueCluster(count.detach().clone(), 1000))
        count = count + cluster_range

    return clusters

if __name__ == '__main__':
    depth_data = torch.tensor([[1150., 1150., 1155., 2041., 2041., 2041.],
            [1153., 1153., 1155., 2048., 2048., 2048.],
            [1150., 1150., 1155., 2048., 2048., 0],
            [890., 893., 0, 0, 0., 0],
            [889., 889., 892., 2560., 0, 0],
            [889., 889., 892., 2549., 2549., 0]])
    clusters = depth_clustering(4, depth_data)
    for cluster in clusters:
        print("Cluster val: {0}, size: {1}".format(cluster.value, cluster.count))

cluster_centers is a list of Python objects each has a center value I assign and a tensor, to which I record points that are closest to it.
The add() method is like a list implementation, which uses tensor and increases its size (by 1000) when its full.
this is ridiculously slow, takes like 4 minutes to run over 300K samples on GPU, is a bit faster on CPU however. So its obvous I'm doing everything incorrectly, but I wasn't able to find any guidance about how to solve this in pytorch way.
I want this to return some data structure that has those cluster centers in it (say X,Y,value) and depth values that were found to be closest to each of the centers.

Make the cluster centers a matrix, detract from the table, and then use argmin to find the appropriate index.

@Zmur, can you provide a minimal reproducible example showing the desired result?

@mknull I tried to do that, if It does not subtract each of cluster center values from each of depth value. But even if it  did that, then I would end up with say 4 matrices with depth differences from each of the cluster centers. How would I compare the differences to see which is the smallest?

I do not want to presume too much, so my guess is to use the same method that you use to assign a centre value. Ivan suggests to provide a minimal example, it is a good suggestion. The question might be underspecified.

@mknull I updated the post with minimal working example as you requested.

@Ivan I updated the post with minimal working example as you requested.
